# pipe babel transpilation without gulp

Tags: node.js, babeljs

So I'm creating a node package which I want to be installable, ideally I'd like to write most of it in ES6 and then have babel transpile it when it gets installed. Obviously the easiest way to do this is with gulp but if possible I'd like to remove the dependency from my package as it's a lot over overhead for something that won't benefit the user at all.

The script I've written to install the filesystem is below but I'd also like to pipe my babel transpilation into that as well. I've given it a good google but all the results I seem to be able to find require gulp. Is there a way (or even a small npm package) that I can easily just add something like `.pipe(babel())` into it?

```
files.forEach( function( file ) {
        var currentFile = scriptDir+file;
        fs.createReadStream(currentFile)
          .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./pdir/core/scripts/'+file));
      })
```

Comment: At some point you need `transform` function from `babel-core`.  This might provide some inspiration: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/tools/buildBabel.js#L8

Comment: hmm... that looks like it will be awkward to use in a stream. Thanks for the nod in the right direction though. At least it gives me something else to research.

Comment: check the babel api as well: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/